# Why sysindexes is much faster than sys.patitions when get table rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know why sys.patitions query run so slow. It spent many time on table 'sysrowsets'. Really confused about this. Anyone can help to answer this question? Thanks a lot!

---

### Runing time

Query 1: 2.7s

Query 2: 19s

---

### Query details

Query 1:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;  
GO 
SELECT
    sys_tables.name AS [TableId],
    sysindexes.rowcnt AS [RowCnt]
FROM
    sysindexes WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS sys_tables WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sys_tables.object_id = sysindexes.id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sys_schemas WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sys_schemas.schema_id = sys_tables.schema_id
WHERE
    sys_schemas.name = 'xxxxxx' AND
    LEN(sys_tables.name) = 26 AND
    sysindexes.indid = 1
GO  
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;
GO
```

Message:

```
(1001 row(s) affected)
Table 'syssingleobjrefs'. Scan count 3003, logical reads 9042, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysidxstats'. Scan count 2002, logical reads 6058, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6835, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysclsobjs'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

Query 2:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;  
GO  
SELECT
    sys_tables.name AS [TableId],
    sys.partitions.rows AS [RowCnt]
FROM
    sys.partitions WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS sys_tables WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sys_tables.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS sys_schemas WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON sys_schemas.schema_id = sys_tables.schema_id
WHERE
    sys_schemas.name = 'xxxxxx' AND
    LEN(sys_tables.name) = 26 AND
    sys.partitions.index_id = 1
GO  
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;  
GO
```

Message:

```
(1001 row(s) affected)
Table 'syssingleobjrefs'. Scan count 3003, logical reads 9468, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysidxstats'. Scan count 1001, logical reads 4057, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysrowsets'. Scan count 1002, logical reads 644644, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3832, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysclsobjs'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: Why are you using `NOLOCK` against system objects?

Comment: @Larnu Because I don't need a entirely accurate count. The result is same after I remove ```WITH (NOLOCK)```. The query use sysindexes still much faster than the other one.